# how to link all libraries i a different project

Tags: c++, cmake, project, actor

I am using CAF(https://github.com/actor-framework) to work on my project, I want to add all the libraries to work_git.

It's working with sqlite3 and here's what I did:

work_git CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(x)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(resources/sqlite3)

add_subdirectory(resources/caf)

add_executable(work_git main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(work_git sqlite3 caf)
```

project structure:

```
|_ _ _ _ work_git
|
|                            _ _ _ _ _ caf
|                           |
|                           |
|_ _ _ _ Resources _ _ _ _ _
|                           |
|                           |
|                            _ _ _ _ _ sqlite3
|
```

Comment: You have to list them all in `target_link_libraries`. Package managers like [Conan](https://conan.io/) create a CMake variable for libraries.

Comment: It's not practical as there are too many libraries!

Comment: If there is no variable containing all libraries it is your only option. You could parse the project using `sed` or `awk` and extract a list of all libraries. You can start with `grep` to find all libraries.

Comment: CAF provides a conan file: https://github.com/actor-framework/conan That solves your problem.

Comment: how is that going to solve my problem?...

Comment: It provides a CMake variable containing all libraries. Something like: `target_link_libraries(work_git sqlite3 CONAN_PKG::caf)`. https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html?highlight=cmake